# Ant build pipeline failing in Azure Devops

Tags: deployment, pipelines

I am trying to run a pipeline in Azure Devops but the build is always getting failed with the following error:

```
Property salesforce.password was circularly defined.
```

This is the pipeline which I have created:

```
# Starter pipeline
# Start with a minimal pipeline that you can customize to build and deploy your code.
# Add steps that build, run tests, deploy, and more:
# https://aka.ms/yaml

trigger:
- dev

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- task: Ant@1
  inputs:
    buildFile: 'build/build.xml'
    options: '-Dsalesforce.password=${salesforce.password} -Dsalesforce.username=${salesforce.username} -Dsalesforce.loginurl=${salesforce.loginurl} -Dsalesforce.testLevel=${salesforce.testLevel}'
    targets: 'deployCheckOnly'
    publishJUnitResults: true
    testResultsFiles: '**/TEST-*.xml'
    javaHomeOption: 'JDKVersion'
```

All the values are added as a variable in Azure

This is the build.xml file:

```
<property file="build.properties"/>
<property environment="env"/>
<property name="ant.jar" value="ant-salesforce.jar"/>
<property name="sf.username" value="${salesforce.username}"/>
<property name="sf.password" value="${salesforce.password}"/>
<property name="sf.serverurl" value="${salesforce.serverurl}"/>
<property name="sf.testlevel" value="${salesforce.testlevel}"/> 

<!-- Setting default value for username, password and session id properties to empty string 
     so unset values are treated as empty. Without this, ant expressions such as ${sf.username}
     will be treated literally.
-->
<condition property="sf.username" value=""> <not> <isset property="sf.username"/> </not> </condition>
<condition property="sf.password" value=""> <not> <isset property="sf.password"/> </not> </condition>
<condition property="sf.serverurl" value=""> <not> <isset property="sf.serverurl"/> </not> </condition>
<condition property="sf.testlevel" value=""> <not> <isset property="sf.testlevel"/> </not> </condition>

<path id="classpath">
    <fileset dir="${lib.dir}" includes="**/*.jar"/>
    </path>

<taskdef resource="com/salesforce/antlib.xml" uri="antlib:com.salesforce">
    <classpath>
        <pathelement location="${ant.jar}" />           
    </classpath>
</taskdef>

<!-- Test out deploy and retrieve verbs for package 'mypkg' -->
<target name="test">
  <!-- Upload the contents of the "mypkg" package -->
  <sf:deploy username="${sf.username}" password="${sf.password}" sessionId="${sf.sessionId}" serverurl="${sf.serverurl}" maxPoll="${sf.maxPoll}" deployRoot="mypkg" rollbackOnError="true"/>
  <mkdir dir="retrieveOutput"/>
  <!-- Retrieve the contents into another directory -->
  <sf:retrieve username="${sf.username}" password="${sf.password}" sessionId="${sf.sessionId}" serverurl="${sf.serverurl}" maxPoll="${sf.maxPoll}" retrieveTarget="retrieveOutput" packageNames="MyPkg"/>
</target>

<!-- Retrieve an unpackaged set of metadata from your org -->
<!-- The file unpackaged/package.xml lists what is to be retrieved -->
<target name="retrieveUnpackaged">
  <mkdir dir="retrieveUnpackaged"/>
  <!-- Retrieve the contents into another directory -->
  <sf:retrieve username="${sf.username}" password="${sf.password}" sessionId="${sf.sessionId}" serverurl="${sf.serverurl}" maxPoll="${sf.maxPoll}" retrieveTarget="retrieveUnpackaged" unpackaged="unpackaged/package.xml"/>
</target>

<!-- Retrieve all the items of a particular metadata type -->
<target name="bulkRetrieve">
<sf:bulkRetrieve username="${sf.username}" password="${sf.password}" sessionId="${sf.sessionId}" serverurl="${sf.serverurl}" maxPoll="${sf.maxPoll}" metadataType="${sf.metadataType}" retrieveTarget="retrieveUnpackaged"/>
</target>

<!-- Retrieve metadata for all the packages specified under packageNames -->
<target name="retrievePkg">
  <sf:retrieve username="${sf.username}" password="${sf.password}" sessionId="${sf.sessionId}" serverurl="${sf.serverurl}" maxPoll="${sf.maxPoll}" retrieveTarget="retrieveOutput" packageNames="${sf.pkgName}"/>
</target>

<!-- Deploy the unpackaged set of metadata retrieved with retrieveUnpackaged and run tests in this organization's namespace only-->
<target name="deployUnpackaged">
  <sf:deploy username="${sf.username}" password="${sf.password}" sessionId="${sf.sessionId}" serverurl="${sf.serverurl}" maxPoll="${sf.maxPoll}" deployRoot="../force-app" rollbackOnError="true"/>
</target>

<!-- Deploy a zip of metadata files to the org -->
<target name="deployZip">
  <sf:deploy username="${sf.username}" password="${sf.password}" sessionId="${sf.sessionId}" serverurl="${sf.serverurl}" maxPoll="${sf.maxPoll}" zipFile="${sf.zipFile}" pollWaitMillis="1000" rollbackOnError="true"/>
</target>

<!-- Shows deploying code & running tests for code in directory -->
<target name="deployCode">
  <!-- Upload the contents of the "codepkg" directory, running the tests for just 1 class -->
  <sf:deploy username="${sf.username}" password="${sf.password}" sessionId="${sf.sessionId}" serverurl="${sf.serverurl}" maxPoll="${sf.maxPoll}" deployRoot="../force-app" testLevel="RunSpecifiedTests" rollbackOnError="true">
     <runTest>SampleDeployClass</runTest> 
  </sf:deploy>
</target>

 <!-- Shows deploying code with no TestLevel sepcified -->
<target name="deployCodeNoTestLevelSpecified">
  <sf:deploy username="${sf.username}" password="${sf.password}" sessionId="${sf.sessionId}" serverurl="${sf.serverurl}" maxPoll="${sf.maxPoll}" deployRoot="../force-app" rollbackOnError="true"/>
</target>

<!-- Shows deploying code and running tests only within the org namespace -->
<target name="deployCodeRunLocalTests">
  <sf:deploy username="${sf.username}" password="${sf.password}" sessionId="${sf.sessionId}" serverurl="${sf.serverurl}" maxPoll="${sf.maxPoll}" deployRoot="../force-app" rollbackOnError="true"  testlevel="RunLocalTests"/>
</target>

<!-- Shows removing code; only succeeds if done after deployCode -->
<target name="undeployCode">
  <sf:deploy username="${sf.username}" password="${sf.password}" sessionId="${sf.sessionId}" serverurl="${sf.serverurl}" maxPoll="${sf.maxPoll}" deployRoot="../force-app"/>
</target>

<!-- Shows retrieving code; only succeeds if done after deployCode -->
<target name="retrieveCode">
  <!-- Retrieve the contents listed in the file codepkg/package.xml into the codepkg directory -->
  <sf:retrieve username="${sf.username}" password="${sf.password}" sessionId="${sf.sessionId}" serverurl="${sf.serverurl}" maxPoll="${sf.maxPoll}" retrieveTarget="codepkg" unpackaged="codepkg/package.xml"/>
</target>

<!-- Shows deploying code, running all tests, and running tests (1 of which fails), and logging. -->
<target name="deployCodeFailingTest">
  <!-- Upload the contents of the "codepkg" package, running all tests -->
  <sf:deploy username="${sf.username}" password="${sf.password}" sessionId="${sf.sessionId}" serverurl="${sf.serverurl}" maxPoll="${sf.maxPoll}" deployRoot="../force-app" testLevel="RunAllTestsInOrg" rollbackOnError="true" logType="Debugonly"/>
</target>

<!-- Shows check only; never actually saves to the server -->
<target name="deployCodeCheckOnly">
  <sf:deploy username="${sf.username}" password="${sf.password}" sessionId="${sf.sessionId}" serverurl="${sf.serverurl}" maxPoll="${sf.maxPoll}" deployRoot="../force-app" checkOnly="true"/>
</target>
```